# Which God should i pray to get rid of speaking ghost and evil spirits and what mantra should I chant according in Vedas and Hinduism

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, evil, ghosts

I am suffering from speaking ghosts and evil spirits. They sometimes attack me and cause pain in my body.

What do the Vedas say about getting rid of haunting ghosts and evil spirits attached to humans? Are there any specific mantras, slokas, or Gods that I should pray to?

Comment: There isn't enough information here for me to post an answer, but you could start by reading [this](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2012/01/hanuman-worship-to-escape-from-fear-of.html)

Comment: Real life problems can not be solved using answers posted here .. for that we need to consult experts .. your problem seems serious so please consult an expert

Comment: CD R every belief system has its own solution and based on your belief system it depends for me best is get Brahamana madhwa vishnava receit srimad bhagavatham for 7 days in home invite relatives if you can and feed them 7 days thus is called bhagavtha sapthaha this is recommended by sage vedavyas to relieve one of ghosts issue while describing dandukari story

Comment: Daily chant vishnushasrananama goto mantralaya get raghavendra swamigal pathothka sprinkled in your head for 3 days

Answer (score 2):

Sri Hanuman Chalisa has a great power. You can chant it and Sankatmochan Sri Hanuman will definitely help you.

> *भूत पिसाच निकट नहिं आवै ।
> महाबीर जब नाम सुनावै ॥२४॥"*
>
> *Bhoot pisaach nikat nahin aave ।
> Mahabir jab naam sunave ॥ 24 ॥ "*
>
> **Meaning.:**
>
> *Oh Super Brave Mahaveer Sri Hanuman ji! No ghosts or evil spirits come near the ones who remember Your name. Therefore, just remembering Your name does everything!*

> *नासै रोग हरै सब पीरा ।
> जपत निरन्तर हनुमत बीरा ॥२५॥*
>
> *Nase rog hare sab peera ।
> Japat nirantar Hanumant beera ॥ 25 ॥*
>
> **Meaning.:**
>
> *All diseases & pains are destroyed & eradicated
> as one keeps on chanting your name continuously.*

> *संकट तें हनुमान छुडावे ।
> मन क्रम बचन ध्यान जो लावै ॥२६॥*
>
> *Sankat se Hanuman chudave ।
> Man karam bachan dyan jo lave ॥ 26 ॥*
>
> **Meaning.:**
>
> *Lord Hanuman you rescue anyone from difficult situation
> when the person meditates & invokes your name whole heartedly.*

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Chanting.: **"|| ॐ नमो नारायणाय ||" (Om namo nārāyaNāya).**

Followed by **Bhagavadgita, adhyaya 11 sloka 36.**

> *अर्जुन उवाच |*
>
> *स्थाने हृषीकेश तव प्रकीर्त्या
> जगत्प्रहृष्यत्यनुरज्यते च |*
>
> *रक्षांसि भीतानि दिशो द्रवन्ति
> सर्वे नमस्यन्ति च सिद्धसङ्घा: ||*
>
> *arjuna uvācha |*
>
> *sthāne hṛiṣhīkeśha tava prakīrtyā
> jagat prahṛiṣhyaty anurajyate cha |*
>
> *rakṣhānsi bhītāni diśho dravanti
> sarve namasyanti cha siddha-sanghāḥ ||*
>
> ***Arjuna said: O Master of the senses, it is but apt that the universe rejoices in giving You praise and is enamored by You. Demons flee fearfully from You in all directions and hosts of perfected saints bow to You.***

Alternately, chanting **the complete Viswaroopa adhyaya (11th chapter) of the Bhagavad Gita.**